# How can i pass a computed date value from success function of ajax to input type text

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my input type to receive the passed value   :

```
success:function(data){  
   $('#inputMonthsDue').val("<?php $effectiveDate = strtotime('+"+data[15]+" months', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));  echo date('Y-m-d',$effectiveDate) ?>");
   $('#inputContractDue').val("<?php $effectiveDate = strtotime('+"+data[16]+" months', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));  echo date('Y-m-d',$effectiveDate) ?>");                                        
}

<input type='text' class='form-control' id="inputMonthsDue" readonly>
```

i have this code to pass to an input type text but it returns `1970-01-01`.

Comment: is $('#inputMonthsDue') a datetimepicker field ?

Comment: So what is in data?

Comment: <input type='text' class='form-control' id="inputMonthsDue" readonly>

Comment: $('#inputMonthsDue').val("<?php $effectiveDate = strtotime('+"+data[15]+" months', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));  echo date('Y-m-d',$effectiveDate) ?>  ");

Comment: this is my code for passing to the id

Comment: Please add this to the question instead of adding comments. That would help those willing to assist a lot.

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like that. use JS functions in the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

I used this in my Php code then return to success function with the date value already. Thanks for helping ^^

```
$arr[17] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($oldDate. " + {$arr[15]} months"));
```